# Ryzen 1800X overheating despite AIO and fans working

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bios, power-supply, cooling

Yesterday morning I had a working computer. Yesterday after work, I didn't.

I'm running a Ryzen 1800X in an ASUS Crosshair VI Hero, cooled by a Corsair H115i.

It has been running just fine for about 6 months. I haven't overclocked it at all (because this is my first time playing with an AMD CPU).

It boots into the BIOS at about 75C, and quickly climbs to 94C before shutting off.

I performed a BIOS update several weeks ago to version 1701, and when I try to update the BIOS from inside, it says I have the latest version.

If I don't go into the BIOS, it fails at POST saying that there's a CPU Temperature error, and to verify that there is something plugged into the CPU_FAN header on the motherboard (which there already was).

I thought that perhaps there was an issue with the PSU dumping too much power into the board, so I replaced it with a brand new Corsair RM650i, but it was still overheating.

The pump power cable for the H115i plugs into the USB2.0 headers on the motherboard, so I thought maybe the pump wasn't circulating the water, so I replaced it with a new identical cable that came with the RM650i, but there was no change.

I felt the water lines going into and coming out of the H115i mounted to the CPU, and one was definitely hot water, and the other was definitely cold, which tells me that the pump is indeed working.

The Thermal Paste was Arctic Silver 5, and it looks pretty good I think.
[image: CPU Thermal Paste]
[image: H115i Thermal Paste]

According to the BIOS, it starts thermal throttling very quickly, as once it hits 88C(as seen in the picture below) the voltage continues to drop.
[image]

I can take a picture of this later, but the QFanControl in the BIOS has all of the fans/pumps running at 100%.

Because this is my first AMD rig, I don't have another motherboard or processor to test with.

Any ideas?

Comment: is there any play in the cooler when the bracket is attached? Rapid spike at BIOS would mean poor contact IMO, maybe add thin washers (metal or make some out of card stock). Also, if the CPU is overheating, probably a bad idea to flash anything.

Comment: I'll have to check once I get home, but I don't believe so. It goes from 74C to 94C in about 2 minutes.

Comment: @Yorik there is no play in either the cooler or backplate.

Comment: No comment on the heating, but as for the " PSU dumping too much power into the board,". Nope. A PSU does not dump power into  motherboard. It allows **up to** XXX power to be used.   Compare it with a car capable of running 100kmph. In a city with a max of 50kmph it still ride 50kmph, despite being capable of going faster. Similarly your PSU will not go 'faster' when not needed.

Comment: @Hennes I was considering a PSU hardware failure where due to some short circuiting or something similiar, was sending more than 12V to that rail.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @RichShealer I was able to somewhat solve this by buying a new fan-powered heatsink for the CPU. I haven't tried testing the old AIO on a different system, but I suspect something may have failed in the AIO.

Comment: I just replaced my original Enermax LiqTech TR 240 cooler with their Mark II version. The original always ran hot and eventually after 9 months was failing so the CPU would hit 95C and shut off.  Enermax seems to have found the issue, but I haven't been able to get a response from them to get my original replaced.  I bought another because I needed my computer.  The mark II that I installed works great.  Seeing temps between 28 and 49 C normally around 35 C.